# MWPhotoBrowser iOS 7 weird positioning

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, mwphotobrowser

in iOS 7 the MWPhotoBrowser is using weird coordinates for the first displayed image. I looked into the code but I don't get it.

In iOS 6 it is only possible to drag/swipe the images in the browser horizontally, but in iOS 7 its movable into any direction.

Maybe someone has an idea on this.

@see: https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser/issues/126

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As commented on https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser/issues/126#issuecomment-24834650

you need to add

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)]){
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

to the **viewDidLoad** of the **MWPhotoBrowser**.